# Does `sour bunch` mean unusual in some cases?

Tags: meaning, expressions

[This mathematical blog post](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter5_LossFunctions/Ch5_LossFunctions_PyMC3.ipynb) says:

> Statisticians can be a **sour bunch**. Instead of considering their winnings, they only measure how much they have lost. In fact, they consider their wins as negative losses. But what's interesting is how they measure their losses.

I searched **sour bunch** on [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sour%20bunch) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/), didn't find a match.

Does **sour bunch** mean unusual here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Sour", when applied to people, means their personality is "mean spirited" or  "bad-tempered"; they are focussed on the negative.

And “bunch”, as in a *bunch of grapes*, just means “a group of things, joined together in some way.”

Here it is saying that statisticians consider "winnings" as "negative losses", and jokingly suggests that this shows that statisticians are a mean spirited group of people.  It is just a joke, don't read too much into it.

Comment: I strongly disagree with "mean spirited" or "bad-tempered".  It's more "grumpy", "rude" and "angry".

Comment: @RonJohn - Thesaurus.com lists "bad-tempered" as a synonym for "grumpy", and "ill-tempered" as a synonym for "angry", so I'm not convinced there's a ton of difference between all those words.

Answer (score 6):

A bunch of people here means:

> a group of people

[bunch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bunch)

Sour in this sense means:

> unfriendly or easily annoyed

[sour](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sour)

Comment: Exactly; "sour bunch" could be rephrased as "grumpy group".